# Copy remote directory recursively with Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

Is there a way to copy a remote directory recursively with Fabric? I am currently using fabric to build a list of directories to download then using local("scp ...") to download them. The documentation on get() is spares and seems only for single files.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`fabric.operations.get`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.get):

```
from fabric.operations import get as download
lcd('/path/to/local-directory-to-save-to')
download('/path/to/remote_directory', '.')
```